# Difference between initialization of struct slices

Tags: arrays, go, struct

```
type Person struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
}

type PersonInfo []Person

type PersonInfo2 []struct {
   ID int `json:"id"`
}
```

Is there have difference between `PersonInfo` (named slice of named structs) and `PersonInfo2` (named slice of unnamed structs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is how you have to initialize Person objects outside of the PersonInfo/PersonInfo2 initialization. Since PersonInfo2 is an array of the anonymous struct type we know nothing about this type outside of the PersonInfo2 initialization.

So they can both be initialized like this:

```
m := PersonInfo{{1}, {2}}
n := PersonInfo2{{1},{2}}
```

However if we want to append an element of the anonymous struct type we would have to specify the full type:

```
append(n, struct { ID int  `json:"id"` }{3})
```

If we print these out we can see they appear to be the same:
     `fmt.Printf("%+v\n%+v", m, n)`
Outputs:

```
[{ID:1} {ID:2}]
[{ID:1} {ID:2}]
```

However they wont be deeply equal because PersonInfo is an array of type Person and PersonInfo2 is an array of anonymous struct type. So the following:

```
if !reflect.DeepEqual(m,n) {
    print("Not Equal")
}
```

will print "Not Equal".

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/VBjktLdg3H) is a link to see for yourself.

When appending to PersonInfo2 we have to repeat the anonymous struct type for every value we want to append, it is probably better to use PersonInfo as an array of type Person.

Comment: please note, the initialization of the slice is not a problem since you can omit the `elemnt's type` and use only `{}`, the pain comes when you want to append a new element to the slice. https://play.golang.org/p/ZQR0zjEFS-

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Go is using [`structural typing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), that means, as long as the two types have the same underlying type, they are equivalent.

So, for your question: `Person` and `struct{ ID int 'json:"id"'}` is equivalent because they have the same underlying type, and therefore, `PersonInfo` and `PersonInfo2` are also equivalent. I took of the json tags to simplify the example.

```
person1 := Person{1}

pStruct1 := struct{ID int}{2}


pInfo1 := PersonInfo{
    person1,
    pStruct1,
}

pInfo2 := PersonInfo2{
    person1,
    pStruct1,
}


fmt.Printf("%+v\n", pInfo1)
fmt.Printf("%+v", pInfo2);

//outputs
//PersonInfo: [{ID:1} {ID:2}]
//PersonInfo2: [{ID:1} {ID:2}]
```

Code example: https://play.golang.org/p/_wlm_Yfdy2

Answer (score -1):

`type PersonInfo` is an object of `Person`, while `PersonInfo2` is a `class` (or `type` in Golang) by itself. Even though their data structure is similar.

So, when you run DeepEqual() to check the similarity it will turn out to be false.

Example by previous comment:

```
if !reflect.DeepEqual(m,n) {
    print("Not Equal")
}
```

Hope this helps.